# Showing running script progress in winform progressbar

Tags: c#, winforms, vbscript, wsh

I have the following code:

```
Process scriptProc = new Process();
scriptProc.StartInfo.FileName = @"cscript";
scriptProc.Start();
scriptProc.WaitForExit();
scriptProc.Close();
```

And I want to hide that cscript window that will show when I execute the above code. And is there any way I can show the above script progress in a winform progressbar control?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you attach a listener which runs each time the cscript writes to the console? If so, you could monitor progress by parsing the output and thus update the progressbar.

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start a process without showing a new window, try:

```
    scriptProc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
```

To show script progress, you need the script to write its progress text to stdout, then have the calling program read the progress text and display it in your user interface. Something like this:

```
   using ( var proc = new Process() )
    {
        proc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo( "cscript" );
        proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        proc.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler( proc_OutputDataReceived );
        proc.Start();
        proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
        proc.WaitForExit();
        proc.OutputDataReceived -= new DataReceivedEventHandler( proc_OutputDataReceived );

    }

void proc_OutputDataReceived( object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e )
{
    var line = e.Data;

    if ( !String.IsNullOrEmpty( line ) )
    {
        //TODO: at this point, the variable "line" contains the progress
        // text from your script. So you can do whatever you want with
        // this text, such as displaying it in a label control on your form, or
        // convert the text to an integer that represents a percentage complete
        // and set the progress bar value to that number.

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer lead me to a solution of my problem.